# Get selected text in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`, and I want to allow the user to highlight a portion of text and copy it with a button instead of using the default Apple method. The problem is that I can't get the text within the selected range.

Here's what I have:

```
@IBAction func copyButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let selectedRange: UITextRange? = textView.selectedTextRange
    selectedText = textView.textInRange(selectedRange)
    UIPasteboard.general.string = selectedText
}
```

But I'm getting

> UITextView has no member textInRange

and I'm not sure what I should be using instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that `UITextView` method `textInRange` have been renamed to `text(in: Range)` since Swift 3. Btw you forgot to add the `let` keyword in your sentence:

```
if let range = textView.selectedTextRange {
    UIPasteboard.general.string = textView.text(in: range)
}
```